# AWS CLI DynamoDB Called From Powershell Put-Item fails when a value contains a space

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-dynamodb

So, let's say I'm trying to post this JSON via the command line (not in a file because I'm not going to write a file for every invocation of this script) to a dynamo DB table

```
{\"TeamId\":{\"S\":\"One_Space_123\"},\"TeamName\":{\"S\":\"One_Space\"},\"Environment\":{\"S\":\"cte\"},\"StartDate\":{\"S\":\"null\"},\"EndDate\":{\"S\":\"null\"},\"CreatedDate\":{\"S\":\"today\"},\"CreatedBy\":{\"S\":\"someones user\"},\"EmailDistributionList\":{\"S\":\"test@test.com\"},\"RemedyGroup\":{\"S\":\"OneSpace\"},\"ScomSubscriptionId\":{\"S\":\"guid-ab22-2345\"},\"ZabbixActionId\":{\"S\":\"11\"},\"SnsTopic\":{\"M\":{\"TopicName\":{\"S\":\"ATopicName\"},\"TopicArn\":{\"S\":\"AtopicArn1234\"},\"CreatedDate\":{\"S\":\"today\"},\"CreatedBy\":{\"S\":\"someones user\"}}}}
```

Then the result from the CLI is one like this:

```
Unknown options: Space"},"ScomSubscriptionId":{"S":"guid-ab22-2345"},"ZabbixActionId":{"S":"11"},"SnsTopic":{"M":{"TopicName":{"S":"ATopicName"},"TopicArn":{"S":"AtopicArn1234"},"CreatedDate":{"S":"today"},"CreatedBy":{"S":"someones, user"}}}}, user"},"EmailDistributionList":{"S":"test@test.com"},"RemedyGroup":{"S":"One
```

As you can see, it fails on the TeamName property that in the above example is "One Space".  If I change that value to "OneSpace" then instead it starts to fail on the "CreatedBy" property that is populated by "someones user" but if I remove all spaces from all properties I can suddenly pass this json to dynamoDB successfully.

In a working example the json looks like this:

```
{\"TeamId\":{\"S\":\"One_Space_123\"},\"TeamName\":{\"S\":\"One_Space\"},\"Environment\":{\"S\":\"cte\"},\"StartDate\":{\"S\":\"null\"},\"EndDate\":{\"S\":\"null\"},\"CreatedDate\":{\"S\":\"today\"},\"CreatedBy\":{\"S\":\"someonesuser\"},\"EmailDistributionList\":{\"S\":\"test@test.com\"},\"RemedyGroup\":{\"S\":\"OneSpace\"},\"ScomSubscriptionId\":{\"S\":\"guid-ab22-2345\"},\"ZabbixActionId\":{\"S\":\"11\"},\"SnsTopic\":{\"M\":{\"TopicName\":{\"S\":\"ATopicName\"},\"TopicArn\":{\"S\":\"AtopicArn1234\"},\"CreatedDate\":{\"S\":\"today\"},\"CreatedBy\":{\"S\":\"someonesuser\"}}}}
```

I can't find any documentation that tells me I can't have spaces, if I read this in from a file it will post it with the spaces, so what gives?  If anyone has any advice on this matter, I certainly appreciate it.

For what it's worth in Powershell the execution looks like this currently (though I've tried various combinations of quoting the $dbTeamTableEntry variable

```
    $dbEntry = aws.exe dynamodb put-item --region $region --table-name $table --item "$($dbTeamTableEntry)"
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually answer my question so I'm going to leave this open for right now and maybe someone can provide a correct answer but I did solve this by removing -compress from my convertto-json.  For some reason when I get a compressed json body it's having this problem but not when it is a full uncompressed json.